# Why doesn't Kubernetes set a 1 CPU limit for a pod?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

My version Kubernetes is 1.22

I'm taking a Kubernetes CKAD course.

In the resources and limits section it says:

> Let's now look at a container running on a node in the Docker world.
>
> A Docker container has no limit to the resources it can consume on a node.
>
> Say a container starts with one CPU on a node.
>
> It can go up and consume as much resource as it requires suffocating the native processes on the node or other containers of resources.
>
> However, you can set a limit for the resource usage on these parts by default.
>
> Kubernetes sets a limit of one CPU to containers, so if you do not specify explicitly, a container will be limited to consume only one CPU from the node.
>
> The same goes with memory.
>
> By default, Kubernetes sets a limit of 512 Mi on containers.
>
> If you don't like the default limits, you can change them by adding a limit section under the resources section in your file.
>
> Specify new limits for the memory and CPU like this when the pod is created.

I created podr nginx, in which I specified only reguest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx-test
  name: nginx-test
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx-test
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
```

After creating a pod, I saw that the CPU and RAM are unlimited:

```
  Namespace                   Name                                                              CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                                              ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  only-test                   nginx-test                                                        250m (0%)     0 (0%)      64Mi (0%)        0 (0%)         8m33s
```

Maybe this is true for Docker? I am using Containerd.

Comment: I think that kubernetes is only showing the **explicit** limits, doesn't mean that the container doesn't get a default limit of 1 CPU. To be sure you should check the limit at the container itself, not through `kubectl`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. To use the default resources, you need to create LimitRange in a specific namespace.

Examples:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: mem-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      memory: 512Mi
    defaultRequest:
      memory: 256Mi
    type: Container
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      cpu: 1
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: 0.5
    type: Container
```